# Error al hacer un import java.sql.*

Tags: java, javafx

Hace tiempo hice una GUI con JAVAFX la cual me permitía conectarme a una database y jugar con ella un poco.
Ahora quiero retomar otro proyecto como ese, pero no puedo hacer dicho import.

He descargado el [Connector/J 8.0.27](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) de plataforma independiente, agregado como librería al proyecto de Intellij Idea el JAR descargado, e intentado importar dicho paquete, pero no obtengo el resultado esperado.

[image: He aquí una imagen bastante descriptiva del asunto.]

```
package Connection;

import java.sql.*;

public class Conn {
    
}
```

Solamente con esas líneas de código ya me basta para saber que algo está mal. En la propia imagen se puede ver de fondo que sale un error en la importación.

¿Qué es lo que estoy haciendo mal? No logro darme cuenta. ¿Quizá sea alguna versión incompatible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que no estas podiendo registrar las clases sql:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para solucionar esto, no descargues y registres la biblioteca como mòdulo, agrega el .jar directamente en el directorio `/libs` de tu proyecto o agregala desde `Libraries` no desde `Modules`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Oh dios, perfecto! Muchísimas gracias!

Comment: Excelente AQMR saludos.